# psycopg2 INSERT not showing rows in table

Tags: python, docker-compose, psycopg2, psql

My below script doesn't actually insert into the DB despite calling `commit()`. If I `select version()...` I can verify that I'm connected to the DB instance.

```
def main():
    import psycopg2

    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database='dbname',
        user='dbuser',
        password='dbuserpass',
        host='host',
        port= 'port'
    )
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    data = [
        ('red', 'R', '675445300'),
        ('red', 'R', '675445300'),
        ('blue', 'B', '675445301'),
        ('green', 'G', '675445302')
    ]

    print("HERE") # THIS PRINTS
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
        cursor,
        "INSERT INTO colors (name, init, code) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
        data
    )
    
    print("At commit() call") # THIS NEVER PRINTS
    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print("DONE INSERTING") # THIS NEVER PRINTS

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unsure if relevant but this script is running in a container and the db is also running in the container. Docker compose default networking. Again, I can verify connection to the DB if I do `select version()...` and log that out from here. I can also go into the db container/psql and confirm no data gets inserted.

Any tips on why data is not inserting?

Comment: If it never prints the second message, the previous call must be causing the script to crash.

Comment: Or it's hanging, right? cuz there are no logs of any sort. no further output.

Comment: A simple INSERT of one row shouldn't hang unless there's another process locking the table and it's waiting for that to finish. You should be able to use database administrator tools to see if this is happening.

Comment: The docs are there for a reason. Read the `execute_values` section of [Fast Execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) and see how to actually use it. Hint, this `...VALUES (%s, %s, %s)` is wrong.

Comment: Yes to all of the above. Core issue was a data type mismatch on insert. Something about the way I've set up the containers keeps any output hidden though, so I thought it was just hanging.

Comment: No it was not a data type mismatch it was a placeholder and parameters issue. The  placeholder for `execute_values`  is `... VALUES %s ...`(note the single `%s`) and the parameters are either the default of a sequence of sequences(list/tuple) or a sequence of mappings(dict). You where using the placeholder style for a regular `cur.execute()`.

Comment: Sure, but changing that didn't fully resolve what I was seeing. Like I said, core issue was bad types + bad logging.